# How should I write my connection string?

Tags: database, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping

I am newbie with Nhibernate. I have installed NHibernate by using NuGet.

There are a lot of tutorials on NHibernate, but most of them are really old(all of them are presented with Microsoft VS 2008). Except for this from [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nhibernate/nhibernate_quick_guide.htm). So I tried to follow this tutorial step by step. This is my Program.cs:

```
  class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                var cfg = new Configuration();
                String DataSource = "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
                String InitialCatalog = "TutorialsPointDb";
                String IntegratedSecurity = "True";
                String ConnectTimeout = "30";
                String Encrypt = "False";
                String TrustServerCertificate = "False";
                String ApplicationIntent = "ReadWrite";
                String MultiSubnetFailover = "False";

                cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
                {
                    x.ConnectionString = DataSource + InitialCatalog + IntegratedSecurity + ConnectTimeout + Encrypt +
                                         TrustServerCertificate + ApplicationIntent + MultiSubnetFailover;
                    x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                    x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                });

                cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

                var sefact = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();

                using (var session = sefact.OpenSession())
                {
                    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var student1 = new Student
                        {
                            ID = 1,
                            FirstMidName = "Allan",
                            LastName = "Bommer"
                        };

                        var student2 = new Student
                        {
                            ID = 2,
                            FirstMidName = "Jerry",
                            LastName = "Lewis"
                        };

                        session.Save(student1);
                        session.Save(student2);

                        tx.Commit();
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

These code that I just qoute is almost identical with the tutorial from tutorialspoint(the solution name is differ). And I have this Exception:

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 0

from this line: `var sefact = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();`
And after research, from my understanding this exception was caused of bad `ConnectionString`. But my `x.ConnectionString` is just identical with the instruction and I can not understand that what did I miss.

And I am awared of that normally there will by a data name: `hibernate.cfg.xml` in the solution with settings like these:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=localdb\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=TutorialsPointDb</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <mapping assembly="DataTransfer"/>
  </session-factory> 
</hibernate-configuration>
```

But not in this step: Create Data from NHibernate - Basic CRUD Operations part.
So my question is, what did I miss? And how can I resolve this Exception?

### Thank you for reading.

Other Exceptions that I got:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll
>
> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in NHibernate.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   NHibernate.dll

---

Other codes from my project in case you want to check for yourself.
My Database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student]
(
    [ID] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [LastName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL, 
    [FirstMidName] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
)
```

This is my one class Student.cs

```
   namespace TutorialsPoint
    {
        public class Student
        {
            public virtual int ID { get; set; }
            public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
            public virtual string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

And its Student.hbm.xml file

```
  <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?> 

<hibernate-mapping xmlns = "urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
                                     assembly = "TutorialsPoint" namespace = "TutorialsPoint">

    <class name = "Student"> 
        <id name = "ID">
            <generator class = "native"/> 
        </id> 
        <property name = "LastName"/> 
        <property name = "FirstMidName"/> 
    </class> 

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

is related to statement:

> *...But my x.ConnectionString is **just identical** with the instruction and I can not understand that what did I miss...*

Because, the code is declaring params:

```
String DataSource = "(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB";
String InitialCatalog = "TutorialsPointDb";
String IntegratedSecurity = "True";
...
```

which cannot be just concatenated

```
x.ConnectionString = DataSource + InitialCatalog 
     + IntegratedSecurity + ConnectTimeout 
     + Encrypt + ...
```

Because that would lead to result:

```
"(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDBTutorialsPointDbTrue...
```

But we need something like this:

```
x.ConnectionString = $"DataSource={DataSource};"
    + $"InitialCatalog={InitialCatalog};"
    + $"IntegratedSecurity={IntegratedSecurity}"
    + ...
```

to get

```
"DataSource=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;InitialCatalog=TutorialsPointDb;..
```

And that would result in the expected connection string format:

> *key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3;...*

Comment: Thank you so much. Your detailed answer does help me resolve this exception.